# Place of 都 in a sentence meaning all

Tags: grammar

Where is the correct place of 都 in this sentence, before or after time definition? Is there a rule for this?

德国人今天不工作。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

都 is an adverb, so it should go before the verb.

> 德国人今天都不工作。

.. means all Germans aren't working today.

(Time) Subject (or time can go here) (adverb) verb (object)

Time can go either before or after the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Just after ‘德国人今天‘ Why are they so lazy?

Comment: That's what I would have thought myself, but my textbook places it after 今天.

Comment: sorry, I was too quick, forgot 今天， after that is correct

Comment: Just asked a friend: 今天德国人都不工作。is good too.